# get root directory in any operating sytem

Tags: c, directory, operating-system, filesystems, c89

Is there is any way to get the DIR pointer to the root directory, no matter what the operating system? preferably without the macros checking like so `#ifdef _WIN32 #endif (etc..)` so for example in windows pointer to the `C/` folder will be returned.

Comment: Maybe some kind of loop that opens `..` until `opendir()` returns `NULL`?

Comment: The parent directory of `/` on a Unixfike system is also `/`.  Classically, the inode number of both `/.` and `/..` is 2 (the value should be the same, regardless of whether it is actually 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Windows, so I'm not sure if this answer could be as simple as `opendir("/")`, or if the following code will work properly on Windows. However, assuming that `/..` works on Windows, and that `C:/..` returns `NULL`, the following should print all of the items in the root directory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

DIR* _get_root(void) {
    DIR     *d = NULL, *prev = NULL;
    char    *path = malloc(strlen(".") + 1);
    char    *pdir = "/..";

    strcpy(path, ".");

    do {
        if (prev) {
            closedir(prev);
        }
        prev = d;

        path = realloc(path, strlen(path) + strlen(pdir) + 1);
        strcat(path, pdir);

        d = opendir(path);
    } while (d);

    free(path);
    return prev;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    DIR             *root = _get_root();
    struct dirent   *sub;

    while ((sub = readdir(root))) {
        printf("%s\n", sub->d_name);
    }

    closedir(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, before you use that suggestion, just try the simple

```
DIR *root = opendir("/");
```

on Windows and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there is any way to get the DIR pointer to the root directory, no
>   matter what the operating system? preferably without the macros
>   checking like so `#ifdef _WIN32 #endif (etc..)` so for example in
>   windows pointer to the `C/` folder will be returned.

The question presumes that there is a universal concept of a single filesystem root to begin with.  This is not the case.  Windows's in particular is a multi-rooted filesystem, with each drive letter having a separate root, and, moreover, with no absolute sense of a main drive (Windows's system files are not necessarily on the C: drive). In fact, operating systems that support the C language do not have to have hierarchical file systems at all.

Overall, the interpretation of filename strings passed to `fopen()`, `opendir()`, & co. is implementation-dependent, so no, the language does not provide for a universal way to get a `DIR *` to the filesystem root, even on systems where that concept is meaningful in the first place.  And that is a good reason to reconsider why you think you want such a thing -- whatever you suppose you would do with it is probably not as general as you think.